# Reactive zipWith not lazy even when used with defer

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, project-reactor

I have this code with project reactor framework but this applies as well for rxjava1, just tested it (guessing for rxjava2 aswell) and I cannot find a reason why the `zipWith()` operator evaluates its parameter flowable even if the events are filtered beforehand and `defer()` is used.

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

public class TestLazy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
            .filter(s -> s > 4)
            .zipWith(Flux.defer(() -> Flux.just(get1(), get2(), get3())), (a, b) -> a + b)
            .subscribe(System.out::println);

        Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
            .filter(s -> s > 4)
            .flatMap(a -> Flux.defer(() -> Flux.just(fromFlatMap())))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static int fromFlatMap() {
        System.out.println("from flatMap");
        return 0;
    }

    private static int get1() {
        System.out.println("get 1");
        return 1;
    }

    private static int get2() {
        System.out.println("get 2");
        return 2;
    }

    private static int get3() {
        System.out.println("get 3");
        return 3;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
get 1
get 2
get 3
```

For `flatMap()` is not the case. Why this behaviour ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flatMap` never executes its lambda because it never receives any value.

`zipWith` in current versions of the various libraries always subscribe to both of its sources thus the **subscription side-effects** of those `get`s (`println`) get run, even though at the end, there is nothing to zip together.

Comment: Thanks David! Appreciate all the work you do in these projects and still have time to answer community questions.

Comment: Actually my assumption was not correct and for rxjava2/3 it behaves differently from rxjava1/reactor. Defer does makes a difference